# filtering hashmap list with a character

Tags: android, arraylist, filter

I have following list with hashmapped string values from sql server and displayed as list.

```
 List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
 Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
 datanum.put("Name", rs.getString("FirstName"));
 data.add(datanum);
```

I managed to filter the names by doing the following, everything works fine.

```
 List<Map<String, String>> filtered_name;
 filtered_name = data.stream()
                .filter(x -> ("string").equalsIgnoreCase(x.get("Name")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But the solution what I have right now works only if the entered matches completely. Is it possible to filter even with just a character entered ?

**Working**

```
Entered string: john
output: john xxx
        john yyy
```

**What I am looking for:**

```
Entered string: j
output: john xxx
        john yyy
```

Comment: Change equalsIgnoreCase to contains

Comment: @CôngHải your suggestion leads to null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the predicate in the filter to something like this:

```
.filter(x -> x.get("Name").startsWith("string"))
```

This would filter all Maps which have the value of the "Name" key starting with "string".

Comment: I didnt try yet. But I can already filter with my complete string. I just want to filter the list with entering just a letter.,like I mentioned in my question

Comment: @cantona_7 - Yes this could happen. You could reverse the strings in .startsWith by putti g the string which cannot be null (constant) in the first place. Or you could also do an explicit null check and handle null scenario separately, if the first option is not possible.

Comment: mmm i agree. Thanks for you effort. I solved this issue differently.